# Undo reverting changes in one branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-revert

I have created a branch `branch1` from `master`.

created a file `test1.txt` in `branch1`:

**test1.txt**

```
some logic
```

Then I merged `branch1` to master.
But I realized that the logic implemented in `branch1` is not properly tested. So I have removed the logic in `test1.txt` and directly committed in master.

Now the file in master will be like this:

**test1.txt**

```
removed logic
```

Then I switched to `branch1` and tested the logic. Since the logic looks fine, I didn't make any changes to the files.

When I tried to merge these changes to master, it shows the following message:

```
Already up to date.
```

How can I merge these changes to master?

Answer (score 3):

There are several way to do this.

One of them is : on your `master` branch, revert the commit where you deleted the logic

```
git revert <sha1>
```

This will create a new commit, which re-enables said logic.

---

Or you can simply edit the file by hand, to reenable the logic (you may copy/paste the relevant chunk from the version in `branch1`), and commit on `master`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `branch1` was already merged into master and you have made no changes in `branch1` since then.

There's more than one way to proceed.

---

One way is simply to checkout `branch1` and make *some* change, even if it is just adding a newline, and add-and-commit. Now you can checkout `master` and merge `branch1` into it again.

I presume, however, that when you do that, you'll get a merge conflict on your file *test1.txt*. Since you know that the `branch1` version is right, you can say

```
git checkout --theirs test1.txt
git add .
git commit -m'merged branch1 again'
```

That completes the merge, overwriting *test1.txt* in `master` with the incoming version from `branch1`.

---

However, that's not what I would actually do. I would have done something completely different when I discovered that issue with the original merge. I would have *undone* the original merge. Don't make a change in *test1.txt* in `master` directly; instead, just turn back the clock to before you made the merge in the first place.

To do so, get onto `master`, and use `git log` to find out the SHA of the commit just *before* the merge. Then say

```
git reset --hard <SHA>
```

Poof, the merge is gone; Git has no memory that there was ever a merge. Now checkout `branch1` again and test the logic, and if/when it's good, switch to `master` and perform the merge — which you can now do, because `branch1` was never merged into `master` as far as Git is concerned.

(I like this approach best because the resulting story told by the history is accurate.)